# python: list of dict groupby based on similar keys and then filter

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a list of dicts like:

```
data = [
  {'11': {'x': 333, 'priority': 1, 'channels': 40}}, 
  {'11': {'x': 444, 'priority': 2, 'channels': 30}}, 
  {'22': {'x': 000, 'priority': 1, 'channels': 55}}
]
```

I want to groupby the dict elements with similar keys for example:

```
 [
   [{'11': {'x': 333, 'priority': 1, 'channels': 40}}, 
    {'11': {'x': 444, 'priority': 2, 'channels': 30}}], 
   [{'22': {'x': 000, 'priority': 1, 'channels': 55}}]
 ]
```

and then filter the dict elements on the key named `priority` if the group-by list has more than 1 element in it.

desired-output:

```
 [
   {'11': {'x': 333, 'priority': 1, 'channels': 40}}, 
   {'22': {'x': 000, 'priority': 1, 'channels': 55}}
 ]
```

Comment: What makes elements "similar" in your example? The key `11`, or something in the data below it?

Comment: @9000 the key `11` makes it similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data = [
  {'11': {'x': 333, 'priority': 1, 'channels': 40}},
  {'11': {'x': 444, 'priority': 2, 'channels': 30}},
  {'22': {'x': 000, 'priority': 1, 'channels': 55}}
]

tmp = {}
for d in data:
    tmp.setdefault([*d][0], []).append(d)

out = [subl[0] for subl in tmp.values()]  
# to select min priority you can do:
# out = [min(subl, key=lambda k: k[[*k][0]]['priority']) for subl in tmp.values()]

# print it to screen:
from pprint import pprint
pprint(out)
```

Prints:

```
[{'11': {'channels': 40, 'priority': 1, 'x': 333}},
 {'22': {'channels': 55, 'priority': 1, 'x': 0}}]
```

Comment: Awesome, could you be kind to explain a bit?

Comment: @Jackma I create temporary dict `tmp` where I group the elements from list `data` by the key (I extract the key with `[*d][0]`). Then I make output list by grabbing first sublist from each group.

Comment: Is this code consider the `priority` value? when you are changing the order of the '11' dicts you will get the `priority` 2 instead of  `priority` 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a loop:

```
result = []
for group in data:
    result.append(min(group, key=lambda x: list(x.values())[0]['priority']))
```

Comment: It gives the error: `result.append(max(group, key=lambda x: list(x.values())[0]['priority']))
 AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'`

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
from collections import defaultdict

res = defaultdict(list)
for i in data:
    res[list(i.keys())[0]].append(i)
print([min(i, key=lambda x: list(x.values())[0]['priority']) for i in res.values()])
```

Output

```
[{'11': {'x': 333, 'priority': 1, 'channels': 40}}, {'22': {'x': 0, 'priority': 1, 'channels': 55}}]
```

The `defaultdict` will aggregate all dicts with the same key and then the list comperation with the `min` function will return the dict by the min priority.

Comment: Did this answer help you?